# Why is my mango seedling starting to brown?

Tags: seedlings, germination, mango

So I started germinating this mango seed 3 weeks ago and after a few day it started to sprout so I planted it in a way that left the cotyledons exposed and placed a bag over it for humidity, but still left it a little open for air to flow in. The next day I noticed the roots stopped growing and the area exposed to sun on the seed is browning and there’s some mold as well. I’ve tried searching the web to see what I’ve been doing wrong but haven’t come up with anything! This is my first time planting a mango seed, so I just want to know what to avoid and do next time!